# How to find child elements of a specified parent using XML::LibXML?

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

Suppose I have a XML file

```
<table>
    <person>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Adam</Name>
    </person>
    <student>
        <Subject>Math</Subject>
        <Marks>90</Marks>
    </student>
    <employee>
        <ID>7</ID>
        <Name>Bill</Name>
    </employee>
</table>
```

I want to get the child elements of the `table` element. i.e. the output should be `person`, `student` and `employee`. How do I do this with the `XML::LibXML` module in Perl?

Comment: We need to see the code you have written and a description of the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('/table/*')) {
    say $node->nodeName();
}
```

or

```
use XML::LibXML qw( XML_ELEMENT_NODE );

my $root = $doc->documentElement();
for my $node ( grep { $_->nodeType() == XML_ELEMENT_NODE } $root->childNodes() ) {
    say $node->nodeName();
}
```